# ob_end_clean modifies variables as well

Tags: php, ob-start, ob-get-contents

Here is a sample code:

```
ob_start();
include("test.ini");
$string = ob_get_contents();
echo "<br/>";
echo "string: ".$string;
```

and the output:

```
testing = ini
string: testing = ini
```

When I add

```
ob_end_clean();
```

at the end of the code above there is no output on the screen.

I am at least expecting the string to be echoed on the screen? Why is that not seen?

Comment: This case can be reproduced without including the ob_start() as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ob_start();** starts output buffering to the internal buffer not (screen), then when you add ob_get_contents(); it copy the the output from internal buffer still nothing printed,  and when ob_end_clean(); interpreted, it will clear all internal buffer memory, nothing outputed to screen.

Starting from ob_start(); to ob_end_clean(); nothing will be printed, I use this method when including file for preventing printing some white space before sending header.

Comment: I can reproduce the exact same thing if I do not even include ob_start(). How does that work?

Comment: The difference is: ob_start() start output buffering before script ends, while normal buffer output starts when script execution ends.

Answer (score 1):

See the difference between [ob_get_clean()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php), [ob_end_flush()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-flush.php) and [ob_end_clean()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php).

`ob_get_clean` gets the current buffer contents and discards the current output buffer.

`ob_end_flush` discards the contents, but outputs the buffer first.

`ob_end_clean` discards the contents of the topmost output buffer. It will return nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the ob_get_clean() function.